# <Pay> verb raises " Invalid content was found starting with element 'Pay'. One of '{Play"

Tags: twilio, payment-gateway, twilio-twiml

I'm attempting to use the new  feature and every attempt at testing results in a hangup on the outgoing call and a Schema warning in the Debugger that says, " Invalid content was found starting with element 'Pay'. One of '{Play"

My TWiML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Pay paymentConnector="Default" amount="5.25" action="https://www.website.io/pay_action" />
</Response>
```

The call setup is: a Twilio js client initiates an outbound call to the twilio application, which requests TWiML from the server, returning a `<Dial>` verb. At some point, the caller (js client-side) presses a button, which updates the live call with the above TWiML, which then disconnects.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 4):

Spoke with someone from Twilio support and the problem was that I hadn't enabled PCI in my account settings. I had clicked "Enable PCI" and agreed to the terms, but hadn't saved the setting on the page. This cleared the problem up!